# How to get particular name from logs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code where I am getting case details. Now I need to get LogAgent name for the case.

But it is in the activity log table which have the columns `CreatedBy`, `Type` and this table has multiple rows (`Logs`).

Created by has different agent names and type has different values like `LogComment`.

I need to get first `LogComment` from the `Type` column and corresponding created by name.

Could any one please help how to do?

Below is my data and I need to get highlighted row

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73xUu.png)

Comment: @John Cappelletti
 Yeah I have a datetime column too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the first Comment for a particular user

```
Select Top 1 *
 From  YourTable
 Where [Type]='Log Comment'
   and [CreatedBy] = 'Benn'
 Order By yourdatetimecolumn
```

If you want the 1st Comment for each User

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Where [Type]='Log Comment'
 Order By row_number() over (partition by CreatedBy order by yourdatetimecolumn)
```

**Just an aside:**  Best to post sample data and desired results as text.